# How can I execute a function AFTER toggleClass with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The toggleClass('show-flyout hide-flyout') should only be called when the animation is done triggered by `$(parent).toggleClass('opened closed');`

How can I do this?

```
 *$('.drawer-left-trigger').click(function () {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).toggleClass('opened closed');
            $(parent).toggleClass('show-flyout hide-flyout')
        });*
```

This did not help:

```
 $('.drawer-left-trigger').click(function () {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).toggleClass('opened closed',function(){

                    $(parent).toggleClass('show-flyout hide-flyout');
             });

        });
```

Comment: Is it an css animation?

Comment: What's wrong with the first option?

Comment: Please let me know if still it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(parent).toggleClass('opened closed').promise().done(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(parent).toggleClass('show-flyout hide-flyout');
    },1000);

    });
```

Comment: This I have also tried found the hint in another SO solution but still the show-flyout class is immediately applied when the sidebar opens. It should just apply when the sidebar is OPENED.

Comment: ok then you can try with passing time into that function like 1000 or else

Comment: try one more thing I am updating my answer please check that as well and let me know

Comment: Please check now I have applied timeout so it will take time to add class

Comment: I just saw: ".toggleClass has no callback"

Comment: Yes, true but I think this code should work is it not working?

Comment: Your code WORKS! I had to adapt it a bit but it works now for my hierarchy :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an css animation by opened / closed so you should listen when animation end, like:

```
$(parent).one('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEndfunction', function() { 
   $(parent).toggleClass('show-flyout hide-flyout');
});
```

Comment: I use for closed opened => transition: all .35s ease-in-out;

Comment: Just editing to adapt to transition instead of animation

Comment: are these the real names => "transitionend webkitTransitionEndd" ?

Comment: yes, webkit / ms / .. are the prefix to included all browser specs, you should try and let me know